# I have a crash when I want to run my project

Tags: android

I'm still new in learning about Android application. I had a crash when I tried to run my Mainactivity. I designed a register layout, and I was trying to save all the registration information in Firebase, but the crash prevented me even from testing whether the database is working or not.

I have executed the app many times, and this is what Logcat told me:

Logcat:
[image: Logcat]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please create a [mcve] and **do not add errors or code as screenshots**

Comment: Please post your actual code and do not use screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your Application class that extends from `android.app.Application` and initialize Firebase in the entire application process.

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution for this issue and I want to share that with you. I had to go back and modify the dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}`
```

and Also modify

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
```

}

According to [Lovish-Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8534048/lovish-pandey) wrote that make sure that all the firebase dependencies have the same import version